# Derivation of expression with negative sign from expression without negative number

Tags: polynomials

Basically, I have this expression:
$$\frac{A^3\space(A+2B)\space(A+3B)}{B^3\space(A\space(A+2B)+B\space(A+B))}$$
And the resulting expression I want to derive is following:
$$\frac{A^3}{B^3}+2\frac{A^2}{B^2} - \frac{A}{B} +\frac{A\space(A+B)}{A\space(A+2B)+B\space(A+B)}$$

When I expand both expressions I got to the same expanded form and I understand how the minus sign got to the second expression, but I don't know any general process how to solve such problem. So the question is:

**Is there a general way of how to know the steps needed in order to derive the second expression, or experimenting is the only way?**

Comment: Consider this expression as a polynomial in $B$ (treating $A$ as a constant) and use partial fractions.

Comment: It is not clear what "solve the problem" means.  There are many equivalent expressions to this one.  How do you pick the desired one out of the group?  If you are using it in a derivation, the desired one will fit with what you need.  Certainly one can decide to isolate $\frac {A^3}{B^3}$ but why isolate $2\frac {A^2}{B^2}$ instead of $\frac {A^2}{B^2}$?

Comment: Thanks. This is a part of bigger equation and my goal is to have as much A over B fractions in the resulting expression as possible (the order of them or the multiplier before them doesn't matter). I need to substitute A/B with X and when I put it all together the Xs nicely add up and the rest cancels out. But I don't know the steps needed in order to have the A over B fractions in the result.